# Can't update October CMS with "php artisan october:update" command or with Backend Function

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, octobercms

**I can't update all of my October CMS website because I'm getting this error.**

When I use "composer install" it works fine, after "php artisan october:update" the website is broken again and I get this error message.

Because of this problem, the plugins are not updated either.

[image]

```
root@1aa8a5669855:/var/www/html# php artisan october:update

Warning: require(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php70/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Call Stack:
    0.0002     392416   1. {main}() /var/www/html/artisan:0
    0.0024     394392   2. require('/var/www/html/bootstrap/autoload.php') /var/www/html/artisan:16
    0.0094     474816   3. require('/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php') /var/www/html/bootstrap/autoload.php:37
    0.0115     488520   4. ComposerAutoloaderInitce290a037d2cbd6fc6b8d537449d0ac2::getLoader() /var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php:7
    0.0194     640720   5. composerRequirece290a037d2cbd6fc6b8d537449d0ac2($fileIdentifier = '023d27dca8066ef29e6739335ea73bad', $file = '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php70/bootstrap.php') /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:56


Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php70/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

Call Stack:
    0.0002     392416   1. {main}() /var/www/html/artisan:0
    0.0024     394392   2. require('/var/www/html/bootstrap/autoload.php') /var/www/html/artisan:16
    0.0094     474816   3. require('/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php') /var/www/html/bootstrap/autoload.php:37
    0.0115     488520   4. ComposerAutoloaderInitce290a037d2cbd6fc6b8d537449d0ac2::getLoader() /var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php:7
    0.0194     640720   5. composerRequirece290a037d2cbd6fc6b8d537449d0ac2($fileIdentifier = '023d27dca8066ef29e6739335ea73bad', $file = '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php70/bootstrap.php') /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:56

root@1aa8a5669855:/var/www/html# composer dump-autoload
The "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
Generating autoload files

Warning: Uncaught ErrorException: require(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../october/rain/src/Parse/Assetic/Less/lessc.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:71
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(71): Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(/var/ww...', '/var/www/html/v...', 71, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(71): require()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(61): composerRequirece290a037d2cbd6fc6b8d537449d0ac2('cd649ce7b2ed09f...', '/var/www/html/v...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInitce290a037d2cbd6fc6b8d537449d0ac2::getLoader()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/kylekatarnls/update-helper/src/UpdateHelper/UpdateHelper.php(143): include_once('/var/www/html/v...')
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/kylekatarnls/update-helper/src/UpdateHelper/ComposerPlugin.php(45): UpdateHelper\UpdateHelper::check(Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#6 [internal function]: UpdateHelper in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71

Fatal error: composerRequirece290a037d2cbd6fc6b8d537449d0ac2(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../october/rain/src/Parse/Assetic/Less/lessc.inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71
```

composer.json

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type":"vcs",
            "url":"https://github.com/octoberrain/composer-merge-plugin"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.3",
        "october/rain": "1.1.*",
        "october/system": "1.1.*",
        "october/backend": "1.1.*",
        "october/cms": "1.1.*",
        "laravel/framework": "~6.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.16",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "dev-feature/composer-v2 as 1.5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.4|^9.3.3",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.3.3|^1.4.2",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.9",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.*",
        "php-parallel-lint/php-parallel-lint": "^1.0",
        "meyfa/phpunit-assert-gd": "^2.0.0",
        "dms/phpunit-arraysubset-asserts": "^0.1.0"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/concerns/InteractsWithAuthentication.php",
            "tests/fixtures/backend/models/UserFixture.php",
            "tests/TestCase.php",
            "tests/PluginTestCase.php"
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated October CMS System with "composer update", but plugins with "php artisan october:update" command.

I found solution on the docs:

> IMPORTANT: If you are using using composer do NOT run this command without first making sure that cms.disableCoreUpdates is set to true. Doing so will cause conflicts between the marketplace version of October and the version available through composer. In order to update the core October installation when using composer run composer update instead.

So i set **"disableCoreUpdates = true"** on the cms config file and works fine.
I can update all plugins without to update a system.